# Puedo activar metodo onchange al recargar una página?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo una tabla que calcula el total y los subtotales que va acumulando un pedido de una venta. al registrar lo hace muy bien ya que al escribir la cantidad activo el metodo change pero al querer por ejemplo editar esa venta... por ejemplo solo remover el producto al metodo de eliminar ya no le hace caso porque obviamente ya no hicimos un cambio.
Se que sería lógico poner la función de eliminar afuera de esta pero no me ha funcionado ya que la variable total esta dentro de la función onchange.
O hay otra manera de hacerlo?

```
   $("#tablaDetalle").on("change", "input", function(){
          var row = $(this).closest("tr");
          var cantidad = parseFloat(row.find("input:eq(2)").val());
          var precio = parseFloat(row.find("input:eq(3)").val());
          var subtotal = parseInt(cantidad, 10) * parseFloat(precio);
          row.find("input:eq(4)").val(isNaN(subtotal) ? "" : subtotal.toFixed(2));
          var total = 0;
            $(".subtotal").each(function () {
                var stval = parseFloat($(this).val());
                total += isNaN(stval) ? 0 : stval;
            });
            $('.total').val(total.toFixed(2));

            $('.delete-row').click(function(){
                var $fila = $(this).parents('tr');
                var valsub = parseFloat($fila.find('input:eq(4)').val());
                new Promise(function(done){
                    total -= isNaN(valsub) ? 0 : valsub;
                    $('.total').val(total.toFixed(2));
                    done();
                })
                .then(function(){
                   parseFloat($fila.find('#id_detalleventa-0-subtotal').val(0));
                })
            });
        });
```

Comment: Esto parece un duplicado de tu otra pregunta. Si tienes información nueva, debes editar la pregunta original en lugar de añadir nuevas preguntas. Además, te expliqué cómo la única variable que necesitabas era `total` que podías recalcularla en el `click` del `.delete-row`. Parece que eso no te funcionó, ¿podrías indicar cómo?

Comment: Lo saque hacia afuera la funcion delete-row pero como delegado no llego a seleccionar ese selector de delete-row asi :
$('#tablaDetalle').on("click", ".delete-row")(function(){
var $fila = $(this).parents('tr');
var valsub = parseFloat($fila.find('input:eq(4)').val());
new Promise(function(done){
total -= isNaN(valsub) ? 0 : valsub;
$('.total').val(total.toFixed(2));                     done();
                    })
                    .then(function(){
                       parseFloat($fila.find('#id_detalleventa-0-subtotal').val(0));
                    })
                });

Comment: además la variable total esta dentro de la función del change y por ende no aumentara ni disminuirá el valor del total

Comment: Entonces, ¿es el mismo problema?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Acabo de ver tu respuesta y bueno por alguna razón al usar el evento delegado no llega a seleccionar el delete-row y tu respuesta anterior si es que llego a seleccionar ese selector funcionara pero pero si vuelvo agregar otro producto de nuevo como no estamos usando la vriable acumulador de nuevo calculara con esa variable y si es la misma respuesta pero cerrare la otra cuenta disculpa.

Comment: No te digo que cierres la otra pregunta. Lo que digo es que si ésta publicación es la misma que la otra, cierres ésta. La otra tiene más información (aunque sería ideal que incluyeras un [mcve]).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ese mismo día resolví este problema :) y espero que le pueda servir a otra persona si es que llega a tener el mismo problema:

Primero a un campo x de mi tabla le puse un autofocus al cargar la página.

```
   $("#tablaDetalle").on("focus keyup", "tr", function(){
          var total = 0;

          var row = $(this).closest("tr");
          var cantidad = parseInt(row.find("input:eq(2)").val());
          var precio = parseFloat(row.find("input:eq(3)").val());
          var subtotal = cantidad * precio;
          row.find("input:eq(4)").val(isNaN(subtotal) ? "" : subtotal.toFixed(2));

            $(".subtotal").each(function () {
                var stval = parseFloat($(this).val());
                total += isNaN(stval) ? 0 : stval;
            });

            $('.delete-row').click(function(){
                var $fila = $(this).parents('tr');
                var valsub = parseFloat($fila.find('input:eq(4)').val());
                new Promise(function(done){
                    total -= isNaN(valsub) ? 0 : valsub;
                    $('.total').val(total.toFixed(2));
                    done();
                })
                .then(function(){
                   $fila.find('input:eq(4)').val(0);
                })
            });

            $('.total').val(total.toFixed(2));
        });
```

Entonces al querer editar una venta o al querer registrar siempre el autofocus activara a este evento al cargar la página y podemos hacer todas las modificaciones que querramos :)
Deben haber otras soluciones pero esta me funciono.
Espero le sirva a alguien!